# Application.Current.Properties in BroadcastReceiver in Xamarin.Forms application

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, broadcastreceiver

I save some preferences in Application.Current.Properties for my Xamarin.Forms app and have a BroadcastReceiver that needs those preferences. The problem is that Xamarin.Forms is not initialized in the BroadcastReceiver so I need a way to access those variables in native Xamain.Android. Is that possible?

Comment: I do not think this will be able there in my knowledge, a better option could be using `SQLite`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution myself.
I used the Xamarin.Forms source (found [here](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android/Deserializer.cs)) to write a function that reads the values from the same file as they are written to in the forms app. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

> I need a way to access those variables in native Xamain.Android

you could use **DependencyService** ,this functionality enables Xamarin.Forms apps to do anything that a native app can do.

here is a sample for using Android's Toast to show message in shared code:

1.create a interface in shared code:

```
public interface IToast
 {
    void LongAlert(string message);//the parameter could pass to the native platform
    void ShortAlert(string message);
 }
```

2.Android Implementation:

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(ToastAndroid))]
namespace Demo.Droid
{
  class ToastAndroid : IToast
   {
     public void LongAlert(string message)
      {
        Toast.MakeText(Android.App.Application.Context, message, ToastLength.Long).Show();
      }            

     public void ShortAlert(string message)
      {           
        Toast.MakeText(Android.App.Application.Context, message, ToastLength.Short).Show();
       }
   }
}
```

3.call in shared code:

```
DependencyService.Get<IToast>().ShortAlert("short toast);
DependencyService.Get<IToast>().LongAlert("long toast);
```

[DependencyService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction)

Comment: This would not work to get the properties from Application.Current.Properties. You could however use dependency injection to make your own similar solution, but that was not what I was after.